# Structured python docstrings, IDE-friendly

Tags: python, python-2.x, docstring

In PHP I was used to PHPdoc syntax:

```
/** Do something useful
@param first    Primary data
@return int
@throws BadException
*/
function($first){ ...
```

— kinda short useful reference: very handy when all you need is just to recall 'what's that??', especially for 3rd-party libraries. Also, all IDEs can display this in popup hints.

It seems like there's no conventions in Python: just plain text. It describes things well, but it's too long to be a digest.

Ok, let it be. But in my applications I don't want to use piles of plaintext.

Are there any well-known conventions to follow? And how to document class attributes?! [PyCharm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) recipes are especially welcome :)

---

In Python3 there's a [PEP 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#rejected-proposals) for functional annotations. That's not useful for 2.x (2.6, specifically)

Also there's a [PEP 0287](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/) for reStructuredText: fancy but still not structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/doc/sphinxext) standard is well-defined, based around reStructuredText (which is standard within the python ecosystem), and has Sphinx integration.  It should be relatively straight forward to write a plugin for PyCharm which can digest numpydoc.

Sphinx also has references on how to document attributes:  http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html?highlight=autoattribute

Answer (score 2):

I use [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/). It supports comments in reStructured Text, and it generates HTML documentation from those comments (akin to javadoc).